Terra rasterize() failing after update to 1.8 with 'too many values for writing'
Since updating terra to 1.8-5, rasterize() is throwing the following error:
"Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rast': [rasterize] too many values for writing: 84300725 > 83166375"
Data used in example:

NC County Boundaries
MRLC's NLCD

Example:
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)



nlcd <- terra::rast("C:/Users/Eliot/Desktop/terra_test_data/nlcd_2021_land_cover_l48_20230630/nlcd_2021_land_cover_l48_20230630.img")

counties <- sf::st_read("C:/Users/Eliot/Desktop/terra_test_data/NCDOT_County_Boundaries/NCDOT_County_Boundaries.shp") %>%
  st_transform(crs(nlcd))

madison <- counties %>% 
  dplyr::filter(NAME == "Madison")

nlcd <- crop(nlcd, vect(counties), mask = FALSE)

rasterize(vect(madison), nlcd)



Based on some experimentation, this appears to be related to the size of the SpatRaster within the Y parameter.  In my actual code, I am rasterizing many polygons of plant species observations distributed across the species' range; in which case, the SpatRaster must be, at minimum, the size of the species' range.
OS: Windows 11
Raster Version: 1.8.5
R Version: 4.4.2

Perhaps this is a function of you terra options settings set chunk size, which gives another approach to assess, in addition to seeing what those options are. Given the order(s) of magnitude difference in error values, you'll likely need to employ many copies.

this was fixed here: https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1686

This issue has been resolved: https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/1686.
